# How can I figured out why the timer event in my Windows Service isn't firing?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

I have a very basic service

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;
using SystemTimer = System.Timers.Timer;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;

namespace ServiceThatConnectsToADb
{
    public class LrcArchiver : ServiceBase
    {
        private static SystemTimer PageLoadTimer = new SystemTimer(5000);

        public LrcArchiver()
        {
            ServiceName = "SO Archiver";
            CanStop = true;
            CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            AutoLog = true;
            PageLoadTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WritePageToDb);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName + " started");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName + " stopped");
            PageLoadTimer.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void WritePageToDb(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string html;
                using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    html = client.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
                }
                EventLog.WriteEntry("html = " + html.Substring(0, 100));
                using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-300NQR3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SoArchive;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    string nonQuery = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Homepage] ([Html]) VALUES ('{html}')";
                    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(nonQuery, connection))
                    {
                        bool succeeded = command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1;
                        EventLog.WriteEntry(succeeded ? "Saved!" : "Not Saved");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("uh-oh! " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new LrcArchiver());
        }
    }
}
```

which I've installed and started, but the `WritePageToDb` method doesn't appear to be firing as none of its `WriteEntry`s are showing. I see

> SO Archiver started

but nothing after that.

Any idea why this is or how I can debug to find the cause?

Answer (score 3):

You are only setting it to work, but you're not starting the timer.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    PageLoadTimer.Enabled = true;
    EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName + " started");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, i had a problem at some point in time, this works for me. The timer is set for 1 min in this part example

```
  TimerCallback callbacktimer;
  Timer IntervalCheck;


  protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {

   try {

    callbacktimer = new TimerCallback(SomeMethode);
    IntervalCheck = new Timer(callbacktimer, null, TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));



    base.OnStart(args);
   } catch (Exception ex) {

   }

  }

  private void SomeMethode(object o) {


  }
```